# PhoneGap support on Windows RT

Tags: cordova, windows-rt

I would like to know whether PhoneGap supports Microsoft Surface RT development. If so, please direct me to a documentation guide.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to develop Metro-style apps then yes, these apps will work on Microsoft Surface RT and Microsoft Surface Pro. You can also submit the app for distribution via Windows Store.

See the official getting started guide: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_win8_index.md.html#Windows%208%20Platform%20Guide

**[ Update April - 2015]**
Cordova 4.0 has been released since I when posted the answer. Please use this updated documentation instead:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%208%20Platform%20Guide

Comment: @QualityCoder, **do not** add `random` code `formatting` to words that you think are important.  Doing so is entirely inappropriate.  If you continue to submit such edits, you are in danger of getting blocked from editing entirely as reviewers reject incorrect formatting-only changes with regularity.

Comment: Thanks James for the guide!